# Read the values of PDF Acroform Fields in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I need to parse a PDF file with a lot of Acroform fields and extract the field name (/T in PDF markup) and value (/V in PDF markup) for each field. I'd like to do this client side in JavaScript but I'm not finding existing examples or libraries that seem to do this. Does any one have any suggestions on how to approach it?

Edit: I want to do this client side for performance reasons. I will be taking the field values from the PDF and saving them to a database. But for some of the fields I will need to prompt for additional input before saving. I'd like to do that all on the client and then send the values to the server for saving instead of uploading the PDF to the server, parsing it on the server, sending the fields that need additional input back to the client, and then sending those results to be saved.

Comment: Are you open to commercial solutions? Also why is it important to do this client side? Why not just server side?

Comment: Commercial solutions like iText? I was primarily looking for a FOSS solution but if you have a commercial solution to recommend I'd take a look at it. I'll edit the question to explain why I want to do it client side.

Comment: No, not iText, that is a server/desktop only SDK, and will not help you with a client side only solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out not to be that hard to parse what I need out of the PDF and a library would probably be overkill. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
function importPdf(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    const matches = reader.result.match(/((obj)[\s\S]*?(endobj))/g);
    matches.forEach(match => {
      const tIndex = match.indexOf('/T (');
      const vIndex = match.indexOf('/V (');
      if(tIndex > -1 && vIndex > -1) {
        const fieldNameSegment = match.substring(tIndex + 4);
        const fieldNameValue = fieldNameSegment.substring(0,fieldNameSegment.indexOf(')'));
        const valueSegment = match.substring(vIndex + 4);
        const dataValue = valueSegment.substring(0, valueSegment.indexOf(')'));
        console.log(fieldNameValue, dataValue);
      }
    });
  }
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" onchange="importPdf(event)">
```

Comment: This may work for some pdfs but it won't work for others. E.g. for forms with non-flat field hierarchies it won't work as desired.

Comment: @mkl Thanks. I'm no expert on PDFs so I don't even know what type of field hierarchies my PDFs have. Do you have any suggestions on other approaches?

Comment: You will need a pdf library. I don't know much about the javascript cosmos, so I cannot recommend a specific one. Alternatively you can try to implement a small pdf library yourself, Adobe has made a copy of ISO 32000-1 publicly available, you can start from there. But don't think that an easy task.

Comment: @mkl Yeah, I'd like to avoid the roll my own library route if possible. Are there any open source server side (preferably .NET) libraries that you could recommend in case I run into any issues trying to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: By "open source" do you actually want open source to be able to audit or change the library code, or do you mean free to use?

Comment: Free to use is good, open source is better. I was having a hard time finding good libraries other than iText.

Comment: Well, there also are PDFSharp and PDF Clown in the open source. I have used neither of them, though, for form field access lately, so I don't know whether to recommend them.

Answer (score 2):

The company I work for has [PDFTron WebViewer SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer) which can you read through all the form fields, read/edit the values, all client side in the browser, and you can also allow the user to view the entire PDF and manually fill in any fields.

Sample: https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/pdf-forms

> I need to parse a PDF file with a lot of Acroform fields and extract the field name (/T in PDF markup) and value (/V in PDF markup) for each field.

You can see live code in the pdf-forms sample linked above, but this code below would iterate all fields and print the value, if any, to the console.

```
viewerElement.addEventListener('ready', function() {
  var viewerInstance = viewer.getInstance();

  const docViewer = viewerInstance.docViewer;
  const annotManager = docViewer.getAnnotationManager();
  const fieldManager = annotManager.getFieldManager();

  const checkField = (field) => {
    // Do something with data
    const { name, value } = field;
    console.log(name + ' ' + value);
    // Check children fields
    field.children.forEach(checkField);
  }

  docViewer.on('annotationsLoaded', function() {
    fieldManager.forEachField(checkField);
  });
});
```

> I will be taking the field values from the PDF and saving them to a
>   database.

If you just want the field values, you can get that easily from WebViewer, in PDF ISO XFDF XML format, which you can send to your server and merge to the PDF using any PDF SDK that supports XFDF. This way, you can avoid transferring the entire PDF back and forth, and just send the much smaller form field values as XML.

```
var xmlXfdfFieldData = annotManager.exportAnnotations({fields:true, widgets:false, links:false});
```

> for some of the fields I will need to prompt for additional input
>   before saving.

The WebViewer UI/UX is completely customizable so you can interact/prompt the user on which fields to update.

This sample below shows how to change color and opacity of form fields, which would be a starting point you can use to apply your own business logic.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/form-samples#customizing-form-fields